# How exactly do the Linux display device files work?

Tags: devices, console, display, framebuffer

I don't really understand how the Linux display device files work and interact together. What files in the `/dev` tree need to go where and where do they need to connect/point to, in order to show a basic text console on my screen? Are there any resources that provide the equivalent of 'the hip bone connects to the knee bone ...', but for Linux graphics device files? I have searched the web and found surprisingly little information about this topic.

Please note that I am not looking for anything to do with X - I'm referring to a system that just has a basic text console. Also, this question is focused on using the *framebuffer* for text/graphics display - I'm not looking for anything involving DRM.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but on several MacBook Pro's I've access to the second (Radeon) graphics card failed recently (using the original Mac OS). If I've more time, I'm going to try a Linux install; so far I just booted from various pre-made distros. Symptoms are similar to yours: Under both Mac OS and various Linux distros, text mode boot works, but it crashes (black screen) when it tries to enable graphics. Do you have a second in-built graphics card on your Macbook? What happens if you remove the radeon drivers from your distro?

Comment: @dirkt no, this particular MacBook (2,1) has just an onboard intel graphics chip, no second graphics card. As I mentioned in the question, I have removed the i915 and drm kernel modules (for GPU acceleration), but I still get the black screen problem on boot.

Comment: The frustrating thing is, the graphics are *fine* during boot. If I could only get Linux to just *leave the graphics setup alone* as it boots, there would be no problem!

Comment: Can you `ssh` into the booted system and inspect logs, `dmesg` etc.? This should show you what it's loading - it will be difficult to guess what goes wrong, as you built the LFS system.

Comment: @dirkt I can access the log files from a different Linux distro that I have installed on another partition (which is also suffering from some annoying display glitches). However, with this question, really I am looking for a general explanation of how the graphics device files work (or at least, are supposed to), as opposed to trying to troubleshoot my specific problem. Perhaps I could ask about the specific problem in a separate question, so as not to confuse things?

Comment: A full explanation how the complete graphics driver stack in all its possible variations works will be very long... which is why I tried to narrow down the problem to what goes wrong, to concentrate on *this* particular variation. Even for Intel chips there are variations depending on the exact hardware.

Comment: @dirkt I have split the issue-specific question into a separate one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494457/257802). As for this general question: do you know of any external resources that might help me understand better how the display device files work? Thanks for your input.

Comment: MacBook(2,1)? That's a pretty old machine: any models with that designation were sold as new in 2006-2007 only. Yet, it has an EFI firmware: since it does not have a PC-style VGA BIOS, you'll need, at minimum, the `efifb` frame buffer driver to run the display via EFI firmware calls. Once that is in place, the kernel should automatically run a *framebuffer console* text-based display on top of it. `/dev/fd0` will then allow access to the display as a graphics bitmap, `/dev/ttyN` devices as the plain old text-based console terminal, and `/dev/vcsN` or `/dev/vcsa*` as an array of characters.

Comment: However, the EFI firmware interface does not exactly have a thrilling performance, and back in 2006/2007, the EFI firmware was a new thing in the x86 world, so there may be bugs anywhere beyond the exact things Apple used it for. So for both performance and reliability, you might want to use the `i915` framebuffer driver in place of `efifb`. Note that `i915` may require the `intel_agp` module to be loaded *first*, as the GPU interface used either AGP technology or things evolved from it. `i915` should automatically take over the display from `efifb`, with no change to device nodes.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for your comments. I think perhaps you mean `/dev/fb0`, rather than `fd0`? I had `efifb` built into the kernel, and the log files confirmed that it was being used for `/dev/fb0`. Even so, the screen was blacking out once udev started to run.I deliberately left out `i915`, as I suspected it may be causing the problems. I have another distro on the same machine that was using i915 (pre-built generic kernel), but it was also having display issues.

Comment: @telcoM I have actually now declared the system kaput (beyond my skills to repair). The hardware issues seem to be worsening, as now it seems to reboot itself before it gets to the login window, so it is very difficult for me to access the machine at all :-(

Comment: Indeed I meant `/dev/fb0`. I'd blame autocorrect, but probably it was just me being too tired.